# <a> takes on alignment of <p> within <div>

Tags: html

Html noob here. I'm trying to make a division that contains some ordinary text and a download button. I've got a paragraph for the normal text and an anchor with an image for the button. For some reason, the button wants to take the same alignment as the paragraph. I have this code:

```css
p {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
a {
  text-align: right;
}
#downloadText {
  width: 360px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="downloadText">
  <p>In the meantime, would you like to download a fun bubbles game for Linux?</p>
  <p>
    <a href="/resources/bubbles_installer.sh" download>
      <img src="/resources/Download-Button.png" alt="Download Button" height="80" width="200">
    </a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Both the paragraph and the anchor end up aligned left. Why would this be? (note: if I change paragraph to align right, both will align right.) thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear..

Run this snippet, hope it helps you:

```css
#downloadText { 
  width: 360px; 
  position: fixed; 
  bottom: 0px; 
  right: 10px; 
  font-weight: bold;
}

p { 
  font-family: Helvetica; 
  font-size: 16px; 
  text-align: left; 
  line-height: 24px; 
  margin-bottom: 0; 
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
    
a { 
  text-align: right; 
  display: block /* Set display block, the element will move */
}
```

```html
<div id="downloadText">
    <p>
        In the meantime, would you like to download a fun bubbles game for Linux?
    <p> 
    <a href="/resources/bubbles_installer.sh" download> 
        <img src="/resources/Download-Button.png" alt="Download Button" height="80" width="200">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The anchor is an inline element, which means its box is as large as its content. The *box* is positioned to the left because of the paragraph's style. The anchor's content might still be positioned to the right, but it doesn't matter because its width is as large as its content.

You've got a few options:

- set `a { position: absolute; right : 0 }` in the style. Not great, imo
- set the width of the anchor to 100% `a { width : 100%; text-align : right }` I also do not favor this option.
- the most correct one css-wise is to wrap the anchor in another block-level element, e.g. another paragraph:

```css
.installer-container {
  text-align : right;
}
```

```html
<p>
    In the meantime, would you like to download a fun bubbles game for Linux?
</p> 
<p class="installer-container">
  <a href="/resources/bubbles_installer.sh" download> 
    <img src="/resources/Download-Button.png" alt="Download Button" height="80" width="200">
  </a>
</p>
```